# Convert Multidimensional PHP array to javascript array

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to convert a PHP multidimensional array to a javascript array using the JSON encoder. When I do a var_dump, my php array looks like this:

```
array (size=2)
  'Key' => string 'a' (length=1)
  'Value' => string 'asite.com' (length=9)
```

This is the code I'm currently using in my view to try to convert it to a JavaScript array:

```
var tempArray = $.parseJSON(<?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>);
```

Whenever I run this code in the browser, the output of the conversion in the console is this:

```
var tempArray = $.parseJSON([{"Key":"a","Value":"asite.com"}]);
```

Is this the correct structure for a javascript multidimensional array? I'm asking because it keeps giving me this error on the line above:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token o`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do not have to call parseJSON since the output of json_decode is a javascript literal. Just assign it to a variable.

```
var tempArray = <?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>;
```

You should be able then to access the properties as

```
alert(tempArray[0].Key);
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
    $php_array = array(
        array("casa1", "abc", "123"), 
        array("casa2", "def", "456"), 
        array("casa3", "ghi", "789" )
    );

    $js_array = json_encode($php_array);
    echo "var casas = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>

alert(casas[0][1]);

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do not use parseJSON, that's for a string.
Just do:

```
<?php
$php_array = array ('Key'=>'a', 'Value'=>'asite.com');
?>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var tempArray = <?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>;
    console.log(tempArray);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This give me in the console:

```
Object { Key="a", Value="asite.com"}
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was only for strings, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just add single quotes in the js function,like

`var tempArray = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>');`