# PHP to javascript - I want to convert a php multidimensional array to a javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$arr = json_encode($employeeDetails);
```

Should translate into:

```
var arr = '{"0":{"name":"William","bio":"Morbi sed ligula"},"2":{"name":"Grace","bio":"Praesent venenatis"}}';
```

Must return array and get this result:

```
var arr = [[ 'William', 'Morbi sed ligula'],[ 'Grace', 'Praesent venenatis'] ];
```

Comment: Please show us what `$employeeDetails` contains.

Comment: If you want the array in a different format, you need to build an array in the proper format first. You probably need to loop through it and remove all keys recursively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Multidimensional PHP array to javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048140/convert-multidimensional-php-array-to-javascript-array)

Comment: @fab - The OP isn't asking about doing a direct conversion (and they are already using json_encode(), which your dupe suggests). They want to change the format of the response.

Comment: the first json string is the one generated? and the second is how you actually want it?

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach assuming that `$employeeDetails` is

```
$employeeDetails[0][] = ['William'];
$employeeDetails[0][] = ['Morbi sed ligula'];
$employeeDetails[1][] = ['Grace' ];
$employeeDetails[1][] = ['Praesent venenatis'];
```

Then translate this:

```
var arr = '[[["William"],["Morbi sed ligula"]],[["Grace"],["Praesent venenatis"]]]';
```

into this:

```
{"0":{"name":"William","bio":"Morbi sed ligula"},"2":{"name":"Grace","bio":"Praesent venenatis"}}
```

would be something like:

```
var arr = '[[["William"],["Morbi sed ligula"]],[["Grace"],["Praesent venenatis"]]]';

obj = JSON.parse(arr);

var newObj = {};

for (var key in obj )
{
    newObj[key] = {};

    newObj[key]["name"] = obj[key][0][0];
    newObj[key]["bio"] = obj[key][1][0];

}

console.log(newObj);
```

;

to translate this:

```
var obj = '{"0":{"name":"William","bio":"Morbi sed ligula"},"2":{"name":"Grace","bio":"Praesent venenatis"}}';
```

into this:

```
var arr = '[[["William"],["Morbi sed ligula"]],[["Grace"],["Praesent venenatis"]]]';
```

something like:

```
var obj = '{"0":{"name":"William","bio":"Morbi sed ligula"},"2":{"name":"Grace","bio":"Praesent venenatis"}}';


obj = JSON.parse(obj);

var newArray = [];

for (var key in obj )
{
    newArray[key] = obj[key];
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the great answer! It was very enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be rendered as an array rather than an object in the resulting JSON, the PHP array must have sequential numeric keys starting with zero.

In order to achieve this you can reindex the data with `array_values` before you `json_encode` and output.

```
$employeeDetails = array_values(array_map('array_values', $employeeDetails));
```

The `array_values` callback in `array_map` will convert the string keys of the inner arrays to numeric, and the outer `array_values` will reassign sequential numeric keys to the outer array.

---

Depending on how `$employeeDetails` is created, it may be possible to make some changes earlier in your code that would make this pre-processing unnecessary.

For example, an array like the one you're starting with *could have been* created by fetching a set of associative arrays from a database and filtering the results in PHP afterward. In that case, you may be able to exclude the unneeded rows in your query and fetch numerically indexed arrays, so your array will already be in a form that will `json_encode` as arrays.

Comment: I agree with you, I am also studying the possibility of making small changes in the format of the original array. I really appreciate your response!